# Laravel: using 'pluck' On Thousands Of Rows Is Causing 500 Error

Tags: php, laravel

Cannot Figure out why this is happening. Unfortunately all Laravel is spitting out is just Chromes standard 500 Error Page Isn't Working.

I have Front End a table that a User can search Contracts. I have thousands and thousands of rows. The list loads (without filters) with about 22,000+ rows, paginated of corse. I am using a plugin called DataTables to make the tables. When I send the response back to the front end with the table, I also want to pluck all the ids from the contract and send it with the DataTable data as well, which you can do using DataTables `->with()` option.

Ex:

```
return DataTable::eloquent($contracts)
->with(['all_ids' => $contracts->get()->pluck('id')])
```

The problem is, the 500 error keeps happening on the fresh list. BUT if I were to filter the list down to about 500 or so rows, it gives me the response no problem with all the 500 plucked ids.

It seems that the 500 error is stemming from the 22,000 being plucked. Unfortunately, DataTables doesn't send back all the ids in the list, just the paginated (current view) ids. This is my work around to get all the ids possible in the entire result set BUT this is causing some headaches.

Any ideas on how I can get this to perform better?

Comment: Don't use get().  That gets all the data from the rows, then plucks the id from the huge collection.  Pluck the id in the query instead.   Next time, find the actual reason for the 500 error before posting, but I can assume you're hitting a memory error by fetching 22000 full rows.

Comment: Link to `DataTable`? Maybe solution lays in some more efficient method from that class.

Comment: Check your `error_log` to see if you are getting a specific error there. Also, change `$contracts->get()->pluck('id')` to `$contracts->pluck('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return DataTable::eloquent($contracts)
    ->with(['all_ids' => $contracts->get('id')]);
```

`get()` accepts a list of column names, that will be included in `select` part of the query.
If that's not efficient enough, then check if `DataTable` have some API to chunk/paginate fetching all those IDs.

Comment: pluck would be far more efficient for a list of values.

Comment: My understanding is that pluck can only operate on php level while get can operate on sql.

Comment: No, that's not true.  Pluck is a query builder method as well as a collection method.